# Why does AreEquals say two values are not correct when one is in double quotes?

Tags: c#, webdriver, assert

I have following check in my WebDriver script, where I am pulling a date field out of a page.

```
IWebElement crInfo = driver.FindElement(By.Id("crInfo"));
string copyDate = crInfo.Text;
// From the converted string now pulling out the year by index and length
string copyYear = copyDate.Substring(2, 4);
// Get the current year
int nowYear = DateTime.Today.Year;
// Converting the year
nowYear.ToString().Trim();
// Make the comparison to be sure the copyright is using the current date
Assert.AreEqual(copyYear,nowYear);
```

As noted in the snippet what I am trying to do is confirm that the date that appears in the page is the current year, this is just a web front end check that the function put in place is returning the right value.  When I run this though what I see in the NUnit console is:

> error:   Expected: "2012"
>   But was:  2012

I don't really get the difference between the two, is the quoted value a string?  I added the conversion in my script to be sure that they are the same type and added the trim in case there might be white space.

If I want to make this work, what is it that I am not doing to get the Assetion to pass?

Comment: because a String <> to an Int

Comment: One is a string and the other is an int?

Comment: you need to convert the Date to be represented in string use the .ToString() to convert the date to a string .representation

Comment: What you probably want is `string strNowYear = nowYear.ToString().Trim()` instead of your `nowYear.ToString().Trim()` which actually doesn't do very much at all.. Then at the end you compare copyYear and strNowYear.

Comment: Thanks!  That was the whole problem in where I was converting.  I was hoping I wouldn't have to reassign nowYear and just use it as it was

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your types and the assertion:

```
string copyYear = ...
int nowYear = ...
Assert.AreEqual(copyYear,nowYear);
```

That assertion will never *ever* pass, whatever the values are. A string is *never* equal to an integer in C#. While there are languages which do type coercion in this sort of scenario, C# isn't one of them.

Also note that this line is useless:

```
nowYear.ToString().Trim();
```

Strings are immutable in .NET - methods like `Trim()` don't change the string they're called on - they return a new string. You're ignoring that return value... and anyway, you're calling it on a string you completely ignore afterwards. You could use:

```
string nowYearAsString = nowYear.ToString().Trim();
Assert.AreEqual(copyYear, nowYearAsString);
```

... or you could parse `copyYear` to an `int` first instead, and compare that instead:

```
int copyYearAsInt = int.Parse(copyYear);
Assert.AreEqual(copyYearAsInt, nowYear);
```

Comment: This is what I did not get with .NET "Strings are immutable in .NET" being that this is not my primary coding language there are aspects of it I am still not quite used to.  Thanks for the indepth explanation, I appreciate it.

Comment: Giving you the win on this since you took the time to explain this out to me.

Answer (score 2):

copyYear is a string.
nowYear is an int. Your line

```
nowYear.ToString().Trim();
```

does not alter nowYear in any way. The string you meant to compare as a result of this line is not assigned to any variable. You need to do

```
string nowYearStr =  nowYear.ToString().Trim();
```

then compare nowYearStr to copyYear.

Comment: Ahh...I thought it would alter the value so I wouldn't need to reassign it.  Bad move on my part...that was it.  Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelF: How could it alter the value of `nowYear` (which is an `int`) based on *string* operations?

Comment: @JonSkeet .Net is not my primary coding language